# Java to VB.net Migration 2D Array declaration

Tags: java, arrays, vb.net

I have been trying to migrate code and there is a 2d array is returning a null reference exception: Object variable or With block variable not set. now the converter has the following comment about it so I tried to initialize a regular 2d array without the RectangularArray.ReturnRectangularStringArray but I haven't had any success. I'm have a feeling this is the  first of many null exceptions.The code basically takes in two lists one that has  LxWxH of a log that has been precut into a block. and another with types of cuts you can make and their value  and value of scrap. the algorithm maximize the cuts to get the most wood out of a block the summarizes what you got.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class LogMatrix
    Public matrix()() As String
    Dim lumber As List(Of Lumber)
    Public Property RectangularArrays As Object

Public Sub New(ByVal a As Integer, ByVal b As List(Of Lumber))
    'JAVA TO VB CONVERTER NOTE: The following call to the 'RectangularArrays' helper class reproduces the rectangular array initialization that is automatic in Java:
    'ORIGINAL LINE: matrix = new String[a+1][a+1]
    matrix = RectangularArrays.ReturnRectangularStringArray(a + 1, a + 1)
    matrix(a + 1, a + 1)

    lumber = b
    buildMatrix()
    printMatrix()
End Sub

Public Overridable Sub buildMatrix()
    ' Populate our profit table with the values of each cut
    For i As Integer = 0 To lumber.Count - 1
        matrix(lumber(i).width)(lumber(i).height) = "" & lumber(i).value
        matrix(lumber(i).height)(lumber(i).width) = "" & lumber(i).value
        administrator.ListBox1.Items.Add(lumber(i).ToString())
    Next i

    For i As Integer = 1 To matrix.Length - 1
        Dim j As Integer = i
        Do While j < matrix(i).Length
            Dim bestCut As String = "-1"

            ' For a piece of lumber size i by j, try every cut
            For k As Integer = 0 To lumber.Count - 1
                ' Make sure this size cut is possible
                If i - lumber(k).height < 0 OrElse j - lumber(k).width < 0 Then
                    Continue For
                End If

                ' The profit we get from cutting a single board of size cut.size
                Dim cutProfit As Double = lumber(k).value

                ' We can split up the leftovers in one of two ways
                Dim leftover As String = "" & matrix(i - lumber(k).height)(j) & " " & matrix(lumber(k).height)(j - lumber(k).width)
                Dim leftovers As String = "" & matrix(i - lumber(k).height)(lumber(k).width) & " " & matrix(i)(j - lumber(k).width)

                ' Pick the greatest profit from the leftover boards
                Dim leftoverProfits As String
                If count(leftover) > count(leftovers) Then
                    leftoverProfits = "" & leftover
                Else
                    leftoverProfits = "" & leftovers
                End If

                ' Take the highest profit from all possible cuts
                If cutProfit + count(leftoverProfits) > count(bestCut) Then
                    bestCut = "" & cutProfit & " " & leftoverProfits
                End If
            Next k

            ' If no cuts are possible, we can only make 0 profit.
            If count(bestCut) > count(matrix(i)(j)) Then
                matrix(i)(j) = "" & bestCut
            End If
            matrix(j)(i) = matrix(i)(j)
            j += 1
        Loop
    Next i
End Sub

Public Overridable Function count(ByVal str As String) As Double
    If str Is Nothing Then
        Return -1.0
    End If

    Dim count_Renamed As Double = 0.0
    Dim parser() As String = str.Split(New Char() {" "c})
    'Dim parser() As String = str.Split(" ", True)
    For k As Integer = 0 To parser.Length - 1
        If Regex.IsMatch(parser(k), "[a-zA-Z ]*\d+.*") Then
            count_Renamed += Double.Parse(parser(k))
        End If
        'If parser(k).matches("[a-zA-Z ]*\d+.*") Then
        '    count_Renamed += Double.Parse(parser(k))
        'End If
        Next k
    Return count_Renamed
End Function

Public Overridable Sub printMatrix()
    administrator.ListBox1.Items.Add(ControlChars.Lf)
    For i As Integer = 1 To matrix.Length - 1
        For j As Integer = 1 To matrix.Length - 1
            Dim parser() As String = matrix(i)(j).Split(New Char() {" "c})
            ' Dim parser() As String = matrix(i)(j).Split(" ", True)
            For k As Integer = 0 To parser.Length - 1
                If Regex.IsMatch(parser(k), "[a-zA-Z ]*\d+.*") Then
                    Console.Write(Double.Parse(parser(k)) & " ")
                End If
                'If parser(k).matches("[a-zA-Z ]*\d+.*") Then
                '    Console.Write(Double.Parse(parser(k)) & " ")
                'End If
            Next k
            administrator.ListBox1.Items.Add("|" & ControlChars.Tab)
        Next j
        administrator.ListBox1.Items.Add(ControlChars.Lf)
    Next i
End Sub

Public Overridable Function calculate(ByVal log As Log) As Double
    Dim total As Double = 0.0
    Do While log.length > lumber(0).length
        Dim parser() As String = matrix(log.height)(log.width).Split(New Char() {" "c})
        'Dim parser() As String = matrix(log.height)(log.width).Split(" ", True)
        For i As Integer = 0 To parser.Length - 1
            If Regex.IsMatch(parser(i), "[a-zA-Z ]*\d+.*") Then
                ' If parser(i).matches("[a-zA-Z ]*\d+.*") Then
                Dim j As Integer = 0
                Do While j < lumber.Count
                    If Double.Parse(parser(i)) = lumber(j).value Then
                        lumber(j).quantity = lumber(j).quantity + 1
                        total += lumber(j).value
                        log.length = log.length - lumber(0).length
                    End If
                    j += 1
                Loop
            End If
        Next i
    Loop

    Dim leftover As Integer = log.width * log.height * log.length
    lumber(lumber.Count - 1).quantity = lumber(lumber.Count - 1).quantity + leftover
    total += lumber(lumber.Count - 1).value * leftover
    Return total
   End Function
End Class
```

below is a picture of the error[image]

Comment: I see the problem - you also have a property called 'RectangularArrays' which will return 'Nothing' - VB is attempting to call that instead of the helper class.  Use the helper class inserted by the converter (I just tested that and the helper class works fine).

Comment: the converter said that the rectangularArrays property is the helper class? I don't know what to call or pass the arguments of the constructor to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the code to work, you need to include the helper class (actually 'Module') that the converter includes in the conversion. The Module can go anywhere you wish - in another file, or in the same file - that's up to you. (And remove the 'RectangularArrays' object property that you added - there is no reason for that).

```
...
    matrix = RectangularArrays.ReturnRectangularStringArray(a + 1, a + 1)
...
Friend Module RectangularArrays
    Friend Function ReturnRectangularStringArray(ByVal size1 As Integer, ByVal size2 As Integer) As String()()
        Dim newArray As String()() = New String(size1 - 1)() {}
        For array1 As Integer = 0 To size1 - 1
            newArray(array1) = New String(size2 - 1) {}
        Next array1

        Return newArray
    End Function
End Module
```